# How can i update state immutably. react, redux, redux-toolkit

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I'm learning redux, and i've a method `addPosts` to add posts to the list of posts, and I'm doing it like this.

```js
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

var initialState = [{ number: 1 }, { number: 2 }, { number: 3 }, { number: 4 }];

export const postsSlice = createSlice({
  name: "postsSlice",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    addPost: (state, action) => {
      state = [...state, action.payload];
    },
  },
});

export const allPosts = (state) => state.posts;

export const { addPost } = postsSlice.actions;
export default postsSlice.reducer;
```

and using the state like this.

```js
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { addPost, allPosts } from "./postsSlice";

function Posts() {
  var posts = useSelector(allPosts);
  var dispatch = useDispatch();

  return (
    <div>
      {posts.map((post) => (
        <div>{post.number}</div>
      ))}

      {/* add post */}

      <button
        onClick={() => {
          dispatch(addPost({ number: 1 }));
          console.log(posts);
        }}
      >
        addpost
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Posts;
```

using `state.push(action.payload)` works somehow, altough the documentation says not use update state like this, and update in an immutable way.
like this `state = [...state, action.payload]`. it does not update state with this immutable way.

I don't know what is wrong that i'm doing.
thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [this](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/usage/immer-reducers) instead of directly changing into `state` you can return in this way

> `return [...state, action.payload]`

Depending on your definition of `initialState`

Please have a look into working example of [react-redux-toolkit-slice-example](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-redux-toolkit-slice-example-vqqh6j)

**Below is the definition of slice**

```js
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const initialState = [{ number: 1 }];

export const postsSlice = createSlice({
  name: "postsSlice",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    addPost: (state, action) => {
      return [...state, action.payload];
    }
  }
});

export const allPosts = (state) => state.posts || [];

export const { addPost } = postsSlice.actions;
export default postsSlice.reducer;
```

**Defining the reducer(postSlice) in store**

```js
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import postsReducer from "../features/posts/postsSlice";

export default configureStore({
  reducer: {
    posts: postsReducer
  }
});
```

**Use of slice in component**

```js
import React from "react";
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { addPost, allPosts } from "./postsSlice";

const Posts = () => {
  var posts = useSelector(allPosts);
  var dispatch = useDispatch();

  return (
    <div>
      {posts.map((post, key) => (
        <div key={key}>{post.number}</div>
      ))}

      {/* add post */}

      <button
        onClick={() => {
          dispatch(
            addPost({
              number: Math.max(...posts.map(({ number }) => number)) + 1
            })
          );
          console.log(posts);
        }}
      >
        Add Post
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Posts;
```

Comment: They are using an array as their `initialState` and can later just work on that shape - there is no reason to have an object as `state`, apart from the fact that it is easier to add additional properties on that later. That part is perfectly fine.

Comment: agreed, as `initialState` can be have any value. I tried and updated solution in fiddle

Answer (score 1):

You are misreading the wrong documentation for the wrong tool it seems - in a Redux Toolkit `createSlice` reducer, it is always 100% correct to use something like `state.push` to mutably modify the object in the `state` variable.

What you cannot do however is what you are trying here: reassign the `state` variable. That had never any effect in any kind of Redux reducer, unless you would return that `state` variable later.

If you want to do that, you will need to `return [...state, action.payload]` instead and leave the `state` variable alone altogether - it should not be reassigned.

But the recommended way would be that push.

For more, please read [Writing Reducers with Immer](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/usage/immer-reducers)